# constant Download error trying to download mnist

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

The error keeps saying:

`Downloading data from https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/tf-keras-datasets/mnist.npz  16384/11490434 [..............................] - ETA: 10s`

and keeps doing this continuously, The code I wrote is this:

```
import tensorflow as tf

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test)= tf.datasets.mnist.load_data()
print(x_train[0])
```

I am trying to print the array of an image using this command, I know I can do it other ways, but I am trying to use "keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()" specifically. What does this error mean?
**My tensorflow version is 2.6.1 and python is 3.9.7**

The error is shown in the image:
[image]

Comment: Works fine for me on WSL. `python3.9`  `import tensorflow as tf` `ds=tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()` gives `Downloading data from https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/tf-keras-datasets/mnist.npz
11493376/11490434 [==============================] - 3s 0us/step
11501568/11490434 [==============================] - 3s 0us/step`

Comment: Try using mnist.load_data("mnist") instead. When I downloaded Anaconda it worked, but when I uninstalled it, it doesn't work. So I decided to try to make it not work while Anaconda was installed and I got the same error using mnist.load_data("mnist"). So what does mnist.load_data() mean ? is there a version with mnist that I am not aware of? or a version of something that I don't know of?

Answer (score 1):

Ok I figured out what went wrong, it is because the file was not downloading permanently in its folder using python's IDLE. When I had used Jupyter Notebook somehow it installed it permanently. In other words, after python's IDLE downloads the file, the downloading phase will stop and the file will go away and python will continuously keep trying to look for it inorder to completely execute the command. Since it could not, you can say python was chasing its tail.

If you were to manually download it and use the same command, python's IDLE will be able to use it. However if you messed with the manually downloaded file by changing the way the file should be opened and you use another command such as `mnist.load_data("mnist")`, you will have to find that file somehow like how I did, by downloading anaconda and using jupyter Notebook or something similar.

The reason why python's IDLE is doing that I have no clue, but if you can somehow find a way to install it permanently the program will work.